# Error getting the last row of a sheet in Google Sheet archiving macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a macro script that runs in the background of a Google Sheet, which archives (copies and pastes values) from a tab with formulas to a new archive tab without formulas when the number of rows in the formula tab exceeds 10. This allows the sheet to not slow down as the number of rows increases with all the built in formulas.

The macro broke a few days ago and nothing has changed, except for this new error I see in the script editor.

Here is the code to return the last row of the sheet we are archiving (with formulas). And the error message is telling me this part of the code broke.

```
var Direction=SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
var DailySLast =dailySheet.getRange("A"+(dailySheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();
```

And here is the error message pointing to the .getNextDataCell part

```
Exception: Invalid argument
myFunction  @ Code.gs:8
```

Any idea why this is happening?

## ===================
4/20/2021 update

Below is the entire function

```
function myFunction() {
   // Get handles to Daily and Archive sheets
  var dailySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scorecard');
  var appendSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('[Archive] Scorecard');

  //get last row of the daily sheet
  var Direction=SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
  var DailySLast =dailySheet.getRange("A"+(dailySheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();

  //Range of cells to be copied
  var CopyRange = "Scorecard!9:" + DailySLast;

  //Range of cells to be deleted
  var DelRange = "Scorecard!9:" + 2000;

  //get last row of the archive sheet
  var ArchiveSLast =appendSheet.getRange("A"+(appendSheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();

  //copying destination range
  var destrange1 = "[Archive] Scorecard!" + (ArchiveSLast + 1) + ":" + (ArchiveSLast + DailySLast-8);
  var destrange=  dailySheet.getRange(destrange1);

  // Clear the contents only if Underwriting sheet has more than 10 rows of data

  if(DailySLast>10) {

  //copying the data
  var sourceDataValues = dailySheet.getRange(CopyRange).copyTo(destrange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  // Get the formulas from the sheet
  var formulas =  dailySheet.getRange(DelRange).getFormulas();

  // Delete the data from the daily sheet
  dailySheet.getRange(DelRange).clearContent();

  //Put the formulas back in the sheet
  dailySheet.getRange(DelRange).setFormulas(formulas)};

  //Browser.msgBox(DailySLast, Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function testquestion() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1);
  let r = rg.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(r),'Test');
}
```

I get the same result if there are no available rows at the bottom of the spreadsheet

```
Execution log
3:44:46 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:44:46 PM  Error   
Exception: Invalid argument
testquestion    @ ag1.gs:5
```

[image]

> In this case getLastRow()+1 doesn't exist because there are no more rows.

Something like this might solve the problem for you:

```
function testquestion() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  //add this section to prevent error
  let lr=sh.getLastRow();
  let mr=sh.getMaxRows();
  if(lr==mr) {
    sh.insertRowAfter(mr);
  }
  //end of section
  const rg = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1);
  let r = rg.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(r),'Test');
}
```

Update:

```
 function myFunction() {
      // Get handles to Daily and Archive sheets
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scorecard');
      var appendSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('[Archive] Scorecard');
      //add this section to prevent error
      let lr = sh.getLastRow();
      let mr = sh.getMaxRows();
      if (lr == mr) {
        sh.insertRowAfter(mr);
      }
      //end of section
      //get last row of the daily sheet
      var Direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
      var DailySLast = sh.getRange("A" + (sh.getLastRow() + 1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();
    
      //Range of cells to be copied
      var CopyRange = "Scorecard!9:" + DailySLast;
    
      //Range of cells to be deleted
      var DelRange = "Scorecard!9:" + 2000;
    
      //get last row of the archive sheet
      var ArchiveSLast = appendSheet.getRange("A" + (appendSheet.getLastRow() + 1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();
    
      //copying destination range
      var destrange1 = "[Archive] Scorecard!" + (ArchiveSLast + 1) + ":" + (ArchiveSLast + DailySLast - 8);
      var destrange = sh.getRange(destrange1);
    
      // Clear the contents only if Underwriting sheet has more than 10 rows of data
    
      if (DailySLast > 10) {
    
        //copying the data
        var sourceDataValues = sh.getRange(CopyRange).copyTo(destrange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    
        // Get the formulas from the sheet
        var formulas = sh.getRange(DelRange).getFormulas();
    
        // Delete the data from the daily sheet
        sh.getRange(DelRange).clearContent();
    
        //Put the formulas back in the sheet
        sh.getRange(DelRange).setFormulas(formulas)
      };
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how I should re-write the code i attached to fix this? Can the problem be fixed by simply adding rows to the bottom of the sheet?

Comment: I inherited the code from somebody else and I actually didnt post the entire function, so I am not sure how to merge your code with the function I currently have. Apologies for the noob questions

Comment: I have updated the original post to include the entire function, would appreciate any guidance on how to edit the function

Comment: It was giving me error saying sh is not defined. so I added two more lines " const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); const sh = ss.getSheetbyName('Scorecard'); " before the lr and mr var statements. Does that sound right to you? I ran the code and it didnt return an error so I just adjusted the timer to see if this archive macro works at the hour I set